# Devtools tabs for multiple open pages

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use devtools in a separate window, and if I have more than one page that I'm inspecting it opens multiple windows. Anyway to group the devtools windows together to get me tabs for each page it's inspecting?

Comment: No. There's no way.

Comment: Sadly I don't think it's even possible with custom dev tools extensions, seems like it has to be coded in by the dev team